# Putting focus on input field by shortcuts in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I want to put focus on input field by shortcut (**alt+b**, for example). The below code works in Chrome and Firefox, but focus immediately lost in IE and Edge. Some tricks?

```js
let $InputField = $('#InputField');

$(document).on('keydown', event => {
  
  // Alt +B
    if (event.altKey && event.keyCode === 66) {
      console.log('done');
      $InputField.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="InputField" type="text"/>
```

([JSFiddle duplicate](https://jsfiddle.net/uggwuo11/2/))

---

### Shortcuts in web apps (a little bit of off-top)

Most of shortcuts with **ctrl** already used by browsers, and it could not be overridden by JavaScript. Now I see that shortcuts with **alt** does not work properly, too. Will shortcuts problem always be the weak point of web applications?

Comment: That fiddle work just fine in both Edge and IE11 (well, Arrow syntax doesn't work in IE though, but with one that does, shortcut works)

Answer (score 1):

input elements and labels have an accesskey attribute for this purpose. Some keystrokes eg. alt+s (focus on the search box) are used for accessibility purposes.